# Get Records that have multiples in the same group

Tags: sql, sqlite, duplicates, subquery, python-3.8

I have a list of client meetings that are added to a SQLite3 database by Python3.8 from a csv of all scheduled meetings (which is manually downloaded after it gets updated each time a new meeting is scheduled).  Sometimes meetings are rescheduled which results in multiple scheduled meetings for the same person in the quarter even though there is only one "quarterly" meeting in each quarter for each client, and the quarters are not based on calendar year but vary by client.  Sometimes there are also 'special' meetings which are in addition to the regular quarterly meetings. A calendar will have Q1 thru Q4 but it may start on Q2 and end on Q1 depending on how the client year falls versus calendar year.

So what I'm wanting to do is return all of the duplicate client meetings for each quarter so I can manually remove/check them and mark as 'special' or 'other'.  The QTR value is calculated by Python when the record is added based on date and the start of the client's individual year.

If there is an alternate way to accomplish this I'd love to hear it.

**Schema (SQLite v3.30)**

```
CREATE TABLE "Meetings" (
    "id_pk" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "Hipaa" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Meeting_Date"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "CN_Date"   TEXT,
    "QTR"   TEXT,
    "Date_Added"    TEXT,
    "Annual"    TEXT,
    "FLAG"  TEXT,
    UNIQUE("Hipaa","Meeting_Date"),
    PRIMARY KEY("id_pk")
)
```

---

**Query #1**

```
insert into Meetings ("Hipaa", "Meeting_Date", "QTR", "FLAG")
values 

( "JonesTom" , "2020-01-03" ,  "Q1" , "Regular" ),
( "JonesTom" , "2020-04-06" ,  "Q2" , "Regular" ),
( "JonesTom" , "2020-07-10" ,  "Q3" , "Regular" ),
( "JonesTom" , "2020-10-15" ,  "Q4" , "Regular" ),
( "JonesTom" , "2021-01-10" ,  "Q1" , "Regular" ),

( "ConnSar"  , "2020-02-04" ,  "Q1" , "Regular" ),
( "ConnSar"  , "2020-05-07" ,  "Q2" , "Regular" ),
( "ConnSar"  , "2020-08-11" ,  "Q3" , "Regular" ),
( "ConnSar"  , "2020-11-02" ,  "Q4" , "Regular" ),
( "ConnSar"  , "2020-11-16" ,  "Q4" , "Regular" ),
( "ConnSar"  , "2021-02-12" ,  "Q1" , "Regular" ),

( "ZuckMark"  , "2019-01-14" , "Q3" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2019-01-17" , "Q3" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-05-20" , "Q4" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-07-05" , "Q1" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-07-21" , "Q1" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-10-20" , "Q2" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-11-06" , "Q2" , "Regular" ),
( "ZuckMark"  , "2020-01-02" , "Q3" , "Regular" )
;
```

---

**Query #2**

```
select * from Meetings;
```

```
| id_pk | Hipaa    | Meeting_Date | CN_Date | QTR | Date_Added | Annual | FLAG    |
| ----- | -------- | ------------ | ------- | --- | ---------- | ------ | ------- |
| 1     | JonesTom | 2020-01-03   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 2     | JonesTom | 2020-04-06   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
| 3     | JonesTom | 2020-07-10   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 4     | JonesTom | 2020-10-15   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 5     | JonesTom | 2021-01-10   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 6     | ConnSar  | 2020-02-04   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 7     | ConnSar  | 2020-05-07   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
| 8     | ConnSar  | 2020-08-11   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 9     | ConnSar  | 2020-11-02   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 10    | ConnSar  | 2020-11-16   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 11    | ConnSar  | 2021-02-12   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 12    | ZuckMark | 2019-01-14   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 13    | ZuckMark | 2019-01-17   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 14    | ZuckMark | 2020-05-20   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 15    | ZuckMark | 2020-07-05   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 16    | ZuckMark | 2020-07-21   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 17    | ZuckMark | 2020-10-20   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
| 18    | ZuckMark | 2020-11-06   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
| 19    | ZuckMark | 2020-01-02   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
```

---

**Desired Results**

```
| id_pk | Hipaa    | Meeting_Date | CN_Date | QTR | Date_Added | Annual | FLAG    |
| ----- | -------- | ------------ | ------- | --- | ---------- | ------ | ------- |
| 9     | ConnSar  | 2020-11-02   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 10    | ConnSar  | 2020-11-16   |         | Q4  |            |        | Regular |
| 12    | ZuckMark | 2019-01-14   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 13    | ZuckMark | 2019-01-17   |         | Q3  |            |        | Regular |
| 15    | ZuckMark | 2020-07-05   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 16    | ZuckMark | 2020-07-21   |         | Q1  |            |        | Regular |
| 17    | ZuckMark | 2020-10-20   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
| 18    | ZuckMark | 2020-11-06   |         | Q2  |            |        | Regular |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26Fe7j2UQgZjc4PgsFbpQG/1)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want duplicates on `(hipaa, qtr)`. You can use `exists`:

```
select m.*
from meetings m
where exists (
    select 1 
    from meetings m1 
    where m1.hipaa = m.hipaa and m1.qtr = m.qtr and m1.id_pk <> m.id_pk
)
```

Another option is a window count:

```
select *
from (
    select m.*, count(*) over(partition by hipaa, qtr) cnt
    from meetings m
) m
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: I was able to modify to include year so different years don't count as duplicates, and then used the FLAG column to mark ones I've fixed. 




`    drop view "MTG_Dupes"; `
`    Create View "MTG_Dupes" as `
`    select * `
`    from ( `
`    select m.*, count(*) over(partition by Hipaa_Short, Meeting_Type, strftime('%Y',  Meeting_Date) ) cnt `
`    from meetings m where FLAG = "REGULAR" `
`    ) m `
`    where cnt > 1 ; `

Answer (score 1):

With `EXISTS`:

```
select m.* from Meetings m
where exists (
  select 1 from Meetings 
  where Hipaa = m.Hipaa 
  and strftime('%Y', Meeting_Date) = strftime('%Y', m.Meeting_Date)
  and QTR = m.QTR 
  and id_pk <> m.id_pk
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26Fe7j2UQgZjc4PgsFbpQG/3).

Comment: I also need the year to be unique, so something in Q1 in 2019 would not be a duplicate of something in Q1 of 2020.

Comment: @ThatChrisGuy the rows with id_pk 1, 5, 6 shoud not be in your expected results.